# Starting a web browser after the local server starts

Tags: ruby, pipe, thin

I run a local server using Thin server. When it starts successively, it returns a message like this:

```
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

I want to run a web browser right after the server starts successfully. I feel that it should be possible to catch the message from thin using some kind of pipe, and starting a web  browser as soon as that message is received, but am not sure about the details. How can I do that? The code for starting Thin is something like:

```
Rack::Handler::Thin.run(...)
```

so I think that piece of code should be embedded somehow in a pipe.

Comment: What's the goal? To make it easier to start a browser immediately after the server starts whenever you start it? Or to alert you to the fact that the server _has_ started when some random process starts it? (As in, could this be solved with a shell alias: `thin && firefox &` ?)

Comment: The goal is to automatically start the browser right after the server succeeds, but not start the browser until the server has started.

Answer (score 1):

In your shell, type the following:

```
alias thin='/usr/bin/thin && firefox http://localhost:3000/ &'
```

(Or, whatever the path to the `thin` server is.)

Now, from that shell, type `thin` and your server will start and once it succeeds, `firefox` will start.

If you like this, add this to your shell's startup files, such as `~/.bashrc`. (The startup files can be complicated; see the `bash(1)` manpage for full details.)